# JSON_VALUE not working for nested path in extracted json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have log entries that contains a JSON segment. It looks like `API request: <the json>` in the message column. I'm using sql server 2019.

Why doesn't my JSON_VALUE with dot notation work when extracting the request id?

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (
    Message NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @TestData (Message)
VALUES
    ('first now'),
    ('API request: {"path":"/api","query":"","body":"{\r\n    \"request_id\": \"1001349\" }"}'),
    ('API request: {"path":"/api","query":""}');

SELECT
    Message,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(payload.value, '$.body'), '$.request_id') AS working,
    JSON_VALUE(payload.value, '$.body.request_id') AS not_working <- why not?
FROM @TestData
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(
        Message,
        CHARINDEX('{', Message),
        LEN(Message)
    ) AS value
) AS payload 
WHERE Message LIKE 'API request:%'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/xAYl7qSP

Comment: `.body`  is just a string with value `"{\r\n    "request_id": "1001349" }"` - a string doesn't have a `request_id` property  - when you call `JSON_VALUE` it then interprets that string as being JSON https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrjl7.png

Comment: If your original string was `'API request: {"path":"/api","query":"","body":{"request_id": "1001349" }}'` - then `body` would contain an object rather than a string that just happens to be JSON and your original code would work. https://dbfiddle.uk/pD9w7PfJ

Comment: @MartinSmith Right, just noticed that. A bit wierd since it's one object serialized by json.net. I'll dig deeper in to it, thanks.

Comment: Guessing that you serialized it to a string and then passed it back to be serialized again. JSON.Net will not generate this automatically.

Comment: I see that the answer that was here was moderator deleted (maybe Chat GPT?) so have posted one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would work if the JSON being parsed was of the following form

```
{
    "path": "/api",
    "query": "",
    "body": {
        "request_id": "1001349"
    }
}
```

But it isn't. It is like the below.

```
{
    "path": "/api",
    "query": "",
    "body": "{\r\n    \"request_id\": \"1001349\" }"
}
```

So `body` is just a string with contents that happen to be JSON.

`JSON_VALUE(payload.value, '$.body')` returns *a string* with contents

```
{
    "request_id": "1001349" }
```

It is only when you call `JSON_VALUE` on *that* that it gets parsed as JSON and you can query it for its `request_id` property.

Likely this is something you should fix at the JSON creation stage so it looks like the first example in this answer and you don't need to do the double parse.

Comment: Yes, turns out the body property value was a raw post body / JSON itself, thanks for pointing it out